# Concatenate two columns with nan based on condition (python)

Tags: python, concatenation, nan, multiple-conditions

I have two columns in a pandas DataFrame that look like this:

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| a | a b c |
| b | a c |
| c | NaN |
| NaN | d e f |
| NaN | NaN |

I would like to concatenate ColA and ColB such that

- if ColA is in ColB then retain ColB
- if ColA is not in ColB concatenate them
- if either are NaN, then retain the column with values
- if both are NaN, then retain NaN

How would I code this in Python such that the desired output would look like below:

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a b c | a b c |
| b | a c | b a c |
| c | NaN | c |
| NaN | d e f | d e f |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |

Note that **'a'** represents a **word**, and **'a b c'** represent **three words** in a text string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED answer (using pandas DataFrames):
Ok, lets assume you did:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

and your DataFrame is as follows:

```
df
  ColA   ColB
0    a  a b c
1    b    a c
2    c    NaN
3  NaN  d e f
4  NaN    NaN
```

Then you define your combination function:

```
def concat(row):
    a = row["ColA"]
    b = row["ColB"]
    if not pd.isnull(a) and pd.isnull(b):
        return a
    if pd.isnull(a) and not pd.isnull(b):
        return b
    if pd.isnull(a) and pd.isnull(b):
        return np.nan
    if a in b:
        return b
    else:
        return a + b
```

and apply it to your DataFrame (to each row):

```
df.apply(concat, axis="columns")
```

what gives this result:

```
0    a b c
1     ba c
2        c
3    d e f
4      NaN
dtype: object
```

Of course, you can still think about whether you want to do a simple concatenation with a `+` in `concat`, or whether you want to add a space, etc.
You get your final result by:

```
df["ColC"] = df.apply(concat, axis="columns")
```

Over and out.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I have updated the question to specify that the data structure is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @ScottC I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much Lukas... I modified the last line of the concat function to :
return a + ' ' + b   

And that gives me the result I needed for the output in row **1:  b a c**
The rest of it was perfect. This did exactly what I needed - thank you.

I would have upvoted your answer, but I don't have enough reputation points.